# How to determine order of combination in Rejuicer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, minify

I used `Rejuicer` for minify and combine JS files and CSS files dynamically in ASP.NET.
How i can change the order of combination.
Suppose i have three JS file :

> apple.js
>   orange.js
>   banana.js

Now, i want the following order:

> orange.js
>   apple.js
>   banana.js

How i can change the order of file combination? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting up rejuicer, in 'global.asax.cs', you can specify the exact order like so:

```
OnRequest.ForJs("~/combined-{0}.js")

  .Combine
  .File("~/Scripts/orange.js")
  .File("~/Scripts/apple.js")
  .File("~/Scripts/banana.js")
  .Configure();
```